# python - collect full path till leaf on organization tree

Tags: python, tree, breadth-first-search

I got organizations tree stored as json

```
{
    "name": "amos",
    "direct_reports": [
        {
            "name": "bart",
            "direct_reports": [
                {
                    "name": "colin",
                    "direct_reports": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "clara",
                    "direct_reports": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bravo",
            "direct_reports": [
                {
                    "name": "cupid",
                    "direct_reports": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "clever",
                    "direct_reports": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to store full "management path" for each employee, such as:
management_chain["clever"]={bravo,amos}
management_chain["bart"]={amos}

Currently I manage to reach all edges and classify those as employees and managers with code as followed:

```
def get_herarchy(org):
    tmp_obj = {}
    tmp_obj['managers'] = []
    for emp in org['direct_reports']:
        tmp_obj['managers'].append(org['name'])
        print("manager "+org['name'])
        if len(emp['direct_reports'])>0:
            get_herarchy(emp)
        tmp_obj['name'] = emp['name']
        print(emp['name'])
    return tmp_obj
```

But the dictionary doesn't holds the right values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, maybe:

```
def get_chain(org, name):
    if org['name'] == name:
        return [name]
    for emp in org['direct_reports']:
        chain = get_chain(emp, name)
        if chain:
            return [org['name']] + chain
    return None

print(get_chain(org, 'bart'))    # ['amos', 'bart']
print(get_chain(org, 'clever'))  # ['amos', 'bravo', 'clever']
```

UPD: This is how to make a dictionary:

```
def nested_iter(org):
    yield org['name']
    for emp in org['direct_reports']:
        yield from nested_iter(emp)

print({name: get_chain(org, name)[0:-1] for name in nested_iter(org)})
```

Comment: the names are unknown

Comment: Not a problem, see updated answer